# How to address aggregate fanout in the below query

Tags: postgresql, query

I have a table `user`. Every user has a one-to-many relationships with `topic_likes` and `topic_dislikes`. I want to query for a user and have their one-to-many relationships exist in their own column in the result as arrays of JSON objects.

Let's say the below is the `user` table:

```
CREATE TABLE user(
    id UUID NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    email VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    username TEXT NOT NULL,
    creationTimestamp TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL
);
```

`topic_like`:

```
CREATE TABLE topic_like(
    user_id UUID NOT NULL REFERENCES user(id) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE,
    likeable_topic_id INTEGER REFERENCES likeable_topic(id) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    index INTEGER NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE(user_id, index),
    UNIQUE(user_id, likeable_topic_id)
);
```

and `topic_dislike`:

```
CREATE TABLE topic_dislike(
    user_id UUID NOT NULL REFERENCES user(id) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE,
    dislikeable_topic_id INTEGER REFERENCES dislikeable_topic(id) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    index INTEGER NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE(user_id, index),
    UNIQUE(user_id, dislikeable_topic_id)
);
```

What I have now is a query like so:

```
SELECT user.id, email, username, 
json_agg(json_build_object('likeable_topic_id', likeable_topic_id, 'index', topic_like.index)),
json_agg(json_build_object('dislikeable_topic_id', dislikeable_topic_id, 'index', topic_dislike.index))
FROM user
LEFT JOIN topic_like ON user.id=topic_like.user_id
LEFT JOIN topic_dislike ON user.id=topic_dislike.user_id
WHERE user.id='58b6fe31-f3f6-4781-af06-93e29cb05bca'
GROUP BY user.id;
```

But when I do this, I get a result where, if there are 5 `topic_like` records for a given user and 5 `topic_dislike` records for a given user, the resulting output will duplicate every `topic_like` record and every `topic_dislike` record in their JSON arrays five times each. Resulting in a JSON array for each column that contains 25 elements despite there being only 5 records in each corresponding table.

How to restructure this query such that each JSON array only contains as many elements as there are matching records in the corresponding table?

Comment: If you remove the aggregates and group by, how many rows does the base query return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use correlated sub-selects rather than left joins

```
SELECT user.id, email, username, 
    (select json_agg(json_build_object('likeable_topic_id', likeable_topic_id, 'index', topic_like.index)) from topic_like WHERE user.id=topic_like.user_id) liked_json,
    (select json_agg(json_build_object('dislikeable_topic_id', dislikeable_topic_id, 'index', topic_dislike.index)) from topic_dislike WHERE user.id=topic_dislike.user_id) disliked_json
FROM user
WHERE user.id='58b6fe31-f3f6-4781-af06-93e29cb05bca'
```